# delphi xe 5 indy 10 Readbuffer & Adata.size

Tags: delphi

`AData.ReadBuffer` and `AData.Size` using `TIdBytes` does not work Like `TStream`. Is there any way to replace them, because I get errors:

> TIdBytes does not contain a member named Size
>
> TIdBytes does not contain a member named ReadBuffer

I am able to use this code in Delphi 2006 but I have some difficults with understanding when I upgraded to XE5.

I am using Indy UDP server and client.

Comment: "not working" is not a useful problem description. Please [edit] your question to include what specific Indy components you're using, and specific details about what "not working" means. Also, if this is your code, you should know where TIdBytes is defined, because you wrote the code.

Comment: Add `IdGlobal` to your interface uses clause. It has the declaration for `TIdBytes`. You'll have to make quite a few adjustments to your code to convert it to Indy 10 from the version that was in D2006. For instance, `TIdBytes` is an `array of Byte`, so it doesn't have a `.Size` property. You'd use `Length(AData)` instead. There's also no `ReadBuffer` method; as I mentioned, `TIdBytes` is an array of Byte, so it already contains the data internally; you access it directly just like you would any other array.

Comment: You've added more code to your question, but you have not indicated how it relates to your previous code: Your new code doesn't call your old code, and your old code doesn't call your new code. What does the new code have to do with your attempted use of `TIdBytes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.UDPReceiverUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  AudioDataSize: Integer;
  AudioData : Pointer;
begin
  try
    EnterCriticalSection(Section);
    try
      AudioDataSize := Length(AData);
      if AudioDataSize > 10 then
      begin
        try
          if not Player.Active then
          begin
            Player.Active := True;
            Player.WaitForStart;
          end;
        except
        end;
        if BlockAlign > 1 then Dec(AudioDataSize, AudioDataSize mod BlockAlign);
        AudioData := AudioBuffer.BeginUpdate(AudioDataSize);
        try
          BytesToRaw(AData, AudioData^, AudioDataSize);
        finally
          AudioBuffer.EndUpdate;
        end;
      end else
      begin
        Player.Active := False;
        Player.WaitForStop;
      end;
    finally
      LeaveCriticalSection(Section);
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Comment: still no sound also on windows 7 i got this error 
Exception EOSError in module Chatproject.exe at 00029633.

System Error.  Code: 123.

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Error 123 is `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`. Such an error would have to be coming from your `Player` class or your `AudioBuffer` class.  Nothing in this Indy code can raise that error. If this code is not working for you, then your original `TStream`-based code should not have worked, either.

Comment: i posted the entire code up there can you advice me how to fix it thank you in advanced

Comment: Let's not play "spot the difference." Can you please *describe* what's different about your code, and explain why it answers the question?

Answer (score 2):

In early versions of Indy, `AData` was a `TStream`.  `AData` was later changed to `TIdBytes`, which is just a dynamic array of `Byte` values.  You are confusing `TIdBytes` for `TStream`.  Use standard array commands to interact with `TIdBytes`. For example, to discover how many bytes are in the array, use the standard `Length()` function:

```
AudioDataSize := Length(AData);
```

To extract data from an array, you can use the `[]` subscript operator to read a single element, or the `Copy` function to grab multiple elements into another array.  Use `Move()` to copy a range of bytes into some other non-array object, such as a generic block of memory:

```
Move(AData[0], AudioData^, AudioDataSize);
```

Or use Indy's own `BytesToRaw()` function:

```
BytesToRaw(AData, AudioData^, AudioDataSize);
```

Comment: Thank you i tested this but i got no sound when u try to record :(

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but I have no idea what that has to do with your question. You asked how to use `TIdBytes`, and I've showed you. If the answer to your question doesn't solve your problem, then you need to ask a different question that aligns more closely with your actual problem.